# Accessing port 8000 on ubuntu in vmware fusion

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization, python

Disclosure: on the server, I am a nooooob. There I said it.

so I have a vm running ubuntu with a BRIDGED network connection and running a python web-server on port 8000. When I go to `http://localhost:8000/` inside the vm, all is working as expected. But I need to access this web-server from outside the vm on the same machine. I used `ifconfig` to get the local network ip `192.168.1.131` of the ubuntu vm. Now if I visit `http://192.168.1.131` in my browser outside the vm I get a page stating:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

However this is not my python web-server, its something else running on port 80. My python is running in port 8000, and when I got to `http://192.168.1.131:8000` I get:

> Unable to connect
>
> ```
>       Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.131:8000.
> ```

What is going on here? Could ubuntu be blocking incoming connection in `8000` but allowing them on `80`? This is a fresh install on the vm of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit. Any help is appricated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Python web server can choose which address(es) it listens to. It might be listening *only* on the `localhost` address (127.0.0.1) and not on the external IP address 192.168.1.131. On the other hand, Apache (or whatever is responding on port 80) is probably listening on *all* addresses, including both localhost and your external IP address.

To do this with Django, try using:

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

See the [documentation for django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) for further details.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.` is what I get when I start the server, so I think you are probably right.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: I've updated my answer with instructions for Django.

Comment: THAT DID IT! Thank you so much, I'd been struggling with this step in setting up my dev environment for some time.